# open a link in an application like twitter using objective c

Tags: ios, twitter

In twitter, when you click on a link, it would open it and would have a "close" button on the top left corner. When you click close, you would be back at where you left in twitter, not anywhere else.

I would like to do this using Objective C.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have researched but haven't found what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to embed a `UIWebView` in to your application: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: would it allow a user to click on a link? or button? then open the contents of that link?

Comment: Yes, for instance by using `loadRequest:`. Reading the link in my answer and searching for UIWebView examples will uncover hundreds and hundreds of examples for you :)